# foobar challenge stuck on prime number postions

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension

I'm pretty stuck now the assignment is
given N find the the position of N+4 characters in a string of prime.
For example a string of prime numbers is 23571113...

So:
n = 3
number is = 71113

n = 0 
number is = 23571

n cannot be greater than 10000

Here's my code which I racked my brain around being efficient but when I try to do a test case of 10000 its taking too long, which is why I think I'm failing 4 of the 10 test cases:

```
def answer(n):
    # your code here
    n = int(n)
    ID_len = 0
    input_limit = 10000  # adjustable limit for n
    y = 0 # Counter
    if n<= input_limit: #checks to make sure you're under the limit of 10000 for n
        try:
            while (ID_len < (n+5)):
                    y += 2
                    primes = [x for x in range(2, y + 1) if all(x%i for i in range(2,x))]
                    prime_str = ''.join(map(str,primes))
                    ID_len = len(prime_str)
            #print prime_str
            return  prime_str[n:n+5]
        except:
            pass
    else:
        print ("pick a number smaller than {0}".format(input_limit))
```

What can I do to make this more efficient or am I just over thinking this problem?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late... As you noticed, you don't have to compute `primes` on each iteration: just move it out of the loop and replace `y` by an adequate value in the list comprehension. But why keep the computation? If you're not limited by the room, you could just write:

```
prime_str = "23579..." # 10000 chars here
```

Let's assume this is not accepted. There are at least two basic improvements to your code:

- you don't need to build the full `prime_str`;
- you can fasten the `primes` generation.

The first improvement:

```
N = n+5
s = " "*10 # a slice large enough
for prime in primes(): # a generator of primes (see below)
    prime_str = str(prime)
    N -= len(prime_str)
    # add the prime at the end of the slice, 
    # remove chars at the beginning to keep the size
    s = s[len(prime_str):] + prime_str        
    if N<0:
        return s[N-5:N] # return the correctp part of the slice.
```

The second improvement. Of course, you can implement the Sieve of Erathostenes, 
it is maybe overkill here. There's a simple idea: if `a = b * c`, then `b >= sqrt(a)` or `c >= sqrt(a)`. Hence, you can stop looking for divisor of `a` when you reach `sqrt(a)`:

```
def primes():
    return (x for x in itertools.count(2) if all(x % i != 0 for i in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(x))+1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ooh man I think I noticed the problem every loop tries to redo ranges that already have been done. I need to keep a counter of the last prime in the string and start from there.